# ASP.NET MVC with ADO.NET DataServices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller, wcf-data-services

In the project i am working on, i want to use the ADO.NET data services as data access layer. so that other parts of my application (except asp.net mvc web site) could also access it from the same location. I am just not sure if this si the correct model and also for asp.net mvc models I wanted to reuse the data services model, as much as possible and also some how decorate them as required fields etc.

Other option i started looking at was to use RIA services as back end to the MVC site.

I am very confued at the moment and any help would be appriceated.

Comment: Wish I could help, but I'm not sure what your asking.

Comment: Hi jfar, I just want to find out a good architecture for my project. It require a central app logic, being used by MVC application, back-end jobs and other clients. I want that app logic to give me a models, which could be used as it is in the MVC app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look into WCF data services?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx

Comment: I bet he did, WCF Data Services used to be called ADO.NET data services.  ;)

Comment: Thanks Ritik, I have already looked at the WCF Data Services, again it does not provide any model, which I can docrate with annotations etc.